# Get the id of the lookup field along with value in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

In lead object I have a lookup called `Project_Name__c`. How can I get the `Id` of the field in Javascript instead of `value`.

**CMP**

```
<aura:attribute name="mainleadRec" type="Lead" />
```

**JS**

```
var projName1 = component.get("v.mainleadRec.Project_Name__c");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `aura:event` to get the `Id` value.
Fire an event when clicked on a record and send `Id` value using event's `aura:attribute`.

```
<!--c:compEvent-->
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <!-- pass context of where the event was fired to the handler. -->
    <aura:attribute name="context" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```